# Bash Shell “noexec” Option Usage Purpose

Tags: bash, options, set

**-n noexec** ; Read commands and check syntax but do not execute them.

---

Can you give an example of when we will need "**noexec**" which is one of the Bash options?

Can someone give me an example of how to properly use this option?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, make sure you do not have a file named `file` in your directory.

Create this `syntaxErr.bash`:

```
echo X > file
for i in a b c;
    echo $i >> file
done
```

As you can see, it misses a `do` after the for loop. See what happens now:

```
$ bash -n syntaxErr.bash
syntaxErr.bash: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `echo'
syntaxErr.bash: line 4: `    echo $i >> file' 
$ cat file
cat: file: No such file or directory
$ bash syntaxErr.bash
syntaxErr.bash: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `echo'
syntaxErr.bash: line 4: `    echo $i >> file'
$ cat file
X
```

So, you get the syntax error feedback without actually executing the commands. If you are doing something quite important, you may not want to run the script until all syntax errors have been corrected.

Note: This `ctafind.bash` does **not** contain a syntax error:

```
echo X > file
cta file
find . -type z
```

`cat` was misspeled by `cta` and there is no file of type z for `find`. Bash does not report the mistakes if you run it with the `-n` flag.

```
$ bash -n ctafind.bash 
$ bash ctafind.bash 
ctafind.bash: line 2: cta: command not found
find: Unknown argument to -type: z
```

After all, Bash can neither know beforehand if there is executable `cta` nor what are the accepted options of an external command.